# tcolorbox package returns "missing \pdf@unescapehex" warning

Tags: tcolorbox, warnings

I'm using TeXLive 2016, and running with XeLaTeX (the log says "LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3").

The following code gives me a warning, as stated in the question title :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The complete warning says :

> Package loading is aborted because of missing \pdf@unescapehex

The problem seems to link with a `listingsutf8.sty` file, but it resists me, maybe someone can help ?

Comment: It is only an info. Imho you can ignore it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer : I know you're right, but I can't help being annoyed that it's not entirely "clean"...

Comment: You can use the silence package to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 14):

Using `listingsutf8` with XeLaTeX is usually not a good idea.

The `most` option loads the `tcolorbox` libraries loaded by `many` together with

```
listingsutf8 external magazine vignette poster
```

and you probably need none of them. So you can simply do

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
```

and the warning will disappear. For code listings you can use the `minted` library instead.